# Redemption: first attempt to SaveAs on sent item fails after trying to get server message-id

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Following on from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291195/get-messageid-of-a-sent-mail-in-outlook/42303292?noredirect=1#comment88973603_42303292), I am encountering failures for the *first* attempt to call `SaveAs` on an RDOMail object, after using the suggested method in the linked answer to get the server's Message-ID header. I want to get the server message-id because it is the canonical ID (and primary key) for messages for my purposes.

The first attempt to `SaveAs` using method 1024 gives me a *Error in IMessage.GetAttachmentTable: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND*, but if I reattempt the save (that is, run all the code in the saving method again), it succeeds with the save and I can see that it has successfully retrieved the server message-id.

I have tried using 1030 and 1031 for SaveAs and these behave the same (fail first time, then succeed), with 1030 returning a slightly different error: *IConverterSession.MAPIToMIMEStm: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND* (1031 returns same error as 1024).

I have a global field in `ThisAddin` for the Redemption session:

```
Public Shared rSession As Object
```

And I assign it in `ThisAddin.Startup` using RedemptionLoader:

```
rSession = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession
rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
```

Then in my class that manages the saving of emails, I use the suggested method like this:

```
Dim rdoMailItem As Object
Dim MAPI_NO_CACHE = &H209
Dim MAPI_BEST_ACCESS = &H10
Try
    rdoMailItem = ThisAddIn.rSession.GetMessageFromID(someEntryId, , MAPI_BEST_ACCESS + MAPI_NO_CACHE)
    Dim dummyString = rdoMailItem.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F")
    rdoMailItem.SaveAs(someFilePath, 1024)
Catch ex as Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try
```

If I omit the further arguments from the `GetMessageFromID` method, and don't try to get the property using `.Fields(...)`, I don't get the errors and `SaveAs` works first time (but of course, that doesn't give me the server message-id). So this behaviour appears to arise from the special options and field retrieval.

This is using Redemption version 5.15.0.4892; same behaviour for 5.11.0.4476 which I had handy. Outlook 2010, connected to an Office365 exchange account.

Comment: When do you execute that code? Is it immediately after the message is moved to the Sent Items folder?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko very soon after it arrives in sent items, yes. I’ll try waiting for differing periods before running it and see what happens. Do you think it might be that the item hasn’t yet (fully) synced to Exchange?

Comment: That's what I am thinking. Does it *always* fail? Or is it random?

Comment: So far it’s always failed first time. I’ll try some things and report back

Comment: Have the same issue. It looks Outlook need some time to actually save item.